# Conditional SELECT in BIgQuery/SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Busy putting together a bit of an abstract dataset by my recent standards and I've hit a bit of a snag.

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%y', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(Event_Time)) AS Date,
  Campaign_ID,
  (SELECT Activity_ID WHERE Activity_ID IN ("9024844","9033733","9022293","9062686") as Sales),
  (SELECT Activity_ID WHERE Activity_ID IN ("9024799","9001112","9001133","9021942") as Leads),
  Site_ID_DCM,
  Ad_ID,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Other_Data, ';u1=(.+?);u') AS ProductCode, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Other_Data, ';u5=(.+?);u') AS Big3OfferCode,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Other_Data, ';u7=(.+?);u') AS CID,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Other_Data, ';u50=(.+?);u') AS URL,
  DBM_Line_Item_ID
FROM
  `fifth-tangent-233009.dtf_gmp_cm.p_activity_1187025`
WHERE
  DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2021-04-29"
```

Now clearly those extra SELECTs can't be there, but how would I select conditionally from the same column, Activity_ID, based on the value of the particular ID, one set if IDs being Sales, and the other Leads, and then display the respective ID in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `case` do what you want?

```
(CASE WHEN Activity_ID IN ('9024844', '9033733', '9022293', '9062686') THEN Activity_ID) as Sales,
(CASE WHEN Activity_ID IN ('9024799', '9001112', '9001133, '9021942') THEN Activity_ID END) as Leads,
```

Note:  I might suggest just using a boolean column as a flag:

```
(Activity_ID IN ('9024844', '9033733', '9022293', '9062686')) as is_sale,
(Activity_ID IN ('9024799', '9001112', '9001133', '9021942')) as is_Lead,
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you, CASE is what I was after in my head, but the boolean flag is much better way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Or, building on Gordon Linoff's answer, instead of two columns with True/False, make one column with the string 'sales' or 'leads' since the two sets do not overlap.

```
    CASE WHEN Activity_ID IN ('9024844', '9033733', '9022293', '9062686') THEN 'Sales'
         WHEN Activity_ID IN ('9024799', '9001112', '9001133', '9021942') THEN 'Leads' END as activity_type
```